# how can I change the inferior Python process

Tags: python, process

I would like to be able to start Python 3 and ipython from Emacs in an inferior mode buffer. Currently `start interpreter C-c C-p` starts 2.7.
I know there must be a way to change to start another python environment.

Comment: «C-u C-c C-p» should allow you to edit the command-line

Comment: the solution from Rusi works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Customize `python-shell-interpreter` to something else than `python`.

Comment: it does not work. I changed the binding in file python.el and it still runs the python 2.7 with C-c C-p

Comment: That's not the meaning of "Customize". You have to use `M-x customize-variable` for that. While editing the source file can be made to work, it's a bad idea.